# Repoguard with git

Tags: git, bash, svn

Thanks in advance for reading this post.

Here is my question.

Currently, we are using repoguard (which is http://repoguard.tigris.org/) with subversion (SVN) as a precommit hook. Is it possible to use repoguard with git? If yes, can someone show me an example.

Or is there anything that works with git like repoguard work with svn?

Thanks for the help.

Murtaza

Answer (score 0):

Git is mentioned in the graphics on the page you linked, so you can assume it works with it.

Comment: Hello Sven, I know it does have git in the logo pic, but I am not able to find any documentation or examples on how to set it up with git instead of svn. 

Anyone know how to set it up with git or any examples would be great.